# Django model - how to model history and current

Tags: python, django

I want to model Employee, and his contracts. So for example there is Employee1, and can have 3 contracts:
from 01-2021 to 05-2021,
from 05-2021 to 08-2023,
from 08-2023 to 10-2024,

Obviously the last one is current. We can model it with 2 models, and simple FK relationship.
But - in most cases I will not need historical data, but just a current contract. To get it - some manipulation is needed ie.  joining employee with contracts, and filtering based on current date.

I prefer to avoid it, and have (in Employee model?)  some field called "current contract" ??
But then some logic will be needed to update it... when any update/create on Contracts is done.

Is there any inteligent way to handle such cases?

Comment: can employees have two concurrent contracts?

Comment: lets assume not.

Comment: then "current contract" idea seems reasonable to me. Imho, selecting on a employee+date  index isn't that expensive, but if you want to avoid that some logic outside the DB is inevitable

Answer (score 0):

You can have the Employee model and Contract being a Foreign key to Employee.

For example

```
from django.utils impprt timezone

class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # ... other fields

    def get_current_contract(self):
        return self.contract_set.all() \
               # the filter can be optional or customised depending on your use case
               .filter(start_date__lte=timezone.now()) \
               .order_by("-start_date") \
               .first()


class Contract(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField()
   
   class Meta:
       unique_together = ["start_date", "employee"]
```

Something like the above will suffice. There is a restriction to avoid having a contract starting on the same date for the same employee and a method to get the latest contract. That way you can keep a record and also get the latest contract.

You can also add an `is_present` field but that would require always setting every other contract but the current one as False. Hope you understand the logic here.